# What does SSH "fingerprint" help to prevent?

Tags: linux, ssh

I do not understand the role of fingerprint in Linux.

Does it just protect the system from man in the middle attacks? How does it protect? Does is keep attackers from accessing the system?

Comment: Answer is here: https://superuser.com/questions/421997/what-is-a-ssh-key-fingerprint-and-how-is-it-generated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is a server fingerprint in ssh?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61735/what-is-a-server-fingerprint-in-ssh), [How is the server authenticated in ssh?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101413/how-is-the-server-authenticated-in-ssh), [Can an SSH server fingerprint be spoofed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61580/can-an-ssh-server-fingerprint-be-spoofed).